# How do I get more money early in No Man's Sky?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I just started playing No Man's Sky last night and I've already built a couple warp cells for the hyperdrive fuel. But the problem is one of the main pieces, the Suspension Fluid, to craft this was very expensive.

It cost me over 40,000 units just for one in the trade center. **Does this price change over time?**

Obviously different materials will sell for different amounts in the trade center, **but which materials, and other miscellaneous items that I find, should I sell to make more money? Are there certain items and materials that I shouldn't sell?**

I'm aware that you can expand your inventory size on your suit and ship, but I haven't found out how to yet. So my item carrying capacity is limited and would need to make several trips back and forth between planets and out to the trade center to sell.

Comment: This is tangential to your question, but buying the components for a warp cell (particularly, suspension fluid) is terribly inefficient. Suspension fluid costs something like 30k on the market and is only worth like 1k if you sell it (and the components for crafting it are similarly cheap... I think it's like 50 carbon). If you don't have the blueprints to make the lesser items yourself, look around and try to at least buy the antimatter, or failing that (and assuming you have the antimatter recipe), the electron vapor, directly from a trader. They don't cost much more than Suspension Fluid.

Comment: Slightly off topic but related to part of your description, you can expand your suit inventory by looking for drop pods on planets. Every drop pod I've come across has added an extra slot to my suit. I haven't found a way to expand the inventory of a ship but you can interact with 'parked' alien ships in space stations or on planets and offer to buy their ship. Sometimes their ship will have more storage and better equipment, but of course costs quiet a bit of units.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From my experience, there are a few easy ways to earn Units quickly.

1. Look for Gold and Emeril. Some planets will be prolific in Emeril, which can be sold for quite a bit. Gold is also very common, and some formations of gold can yield upwards of 2 stacks of 250.
2. Manipulate the Galactic Market and space-faring traders. [PCGamer](http://www.pcgamer.com/make-money-no-mans-sky/) did a fantastic article on how to make money, but specifically through manipulating the markets. In summary, "Keep an eye out for a yellow star next to certain items: it indicates you can sell these item for a much higher price, usually about 95% more than the galactic average." Buy items for lower prices, sell them for higher. While there are more efficient methods, it can be a quick way to get some Units for a new ship.
3. *Scan EVERYTHING.* Each bit of fauna can give you a small amount of units, both for scanning them and uploading them, but by finding all the species on a single planet, depending on how many there are, there can be huge Unit bonuses involved. The larger the species pool, the larger the reward. From my experience, I earned 350,000 units from scanning all species on one planet. It can be difficult to find everything, but definitely worth it.

The [PCGamer](http://www.pcgamer.com/make-money-no-mans-sky/) article has a few more points, but these are probably the fastest and easiest.

Comment: To be specific, it appears that the "scan all animals on a planet" bonus is 25k * the number of species.

Comment: @Amadeus9 I never made that connection... good to know!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest and most cost effective way I've seen is by crafting and selling Bypass Chips. They only require 10 Plutonium and 10 Iron to craft and they sell for over 3k each. While it's a bit tedious you can wrack up a million credits in 20-30 mins of gathering/crafting and the required resources can be found on almost every planet.

Fastest way to make money when you need it versus relying on running into something worth more or trying to mess around with finding a good market.

Answer (score 2):

Asteroid mining for materials like Copper, Nickel, and Gold can yield large amounts of money very quickly because you can mine the asteroids right near the space stations. Usually the larger size asteroids will have these materials, rather than the smaller asteroids that only have Thamium9.

Answer (score 1):

Suspension fluid becomes trivial when you find the blueprint for it. Use the red beacons to search for the Colonial Outposts, break in (grenades or blaster) and solve the little puzzle inside to find it and other recipes. You can use the red beacons more than once, and the cost is only a bypass chip so you can locate several buildings of each type before heading out.

Gold and Emeril are great starter resources to sell. Alternatively if you get lucky and find a planet with gravitino balls, poison sacs, vortex cores, or aquaspheres collecting them up and selling on planet is the quickest way I've found to get units. They each take a slot, but generally sell for 20-30k units each, and are quite common on the planets when you find them. Bigger inventory capacity will make this more efficient as well.

Comment: The one time I found a gravitino ball it was on a planet with hostile sentinels; is that typical?

Comment: @Random832 this happened to me as well. I picked up the gravitino ball and was immediately attacked.

Comment: @C-dizzle No, I'm not talking about that, that's normal when you take any high-value items - it was a world where they immediately attack on sight. (which was a pain because I'd landed right next to a puddle of freezing water with an abandoned building with no door in it.), so I couldn't spend time walking around looking for stuff.

Comment: @Random832 no, that's not typical, or at least not guaranteed. I've seen planets with resources like that and the sentinels weren't aggressive.

Comment: @Random832 On a planet where the sentinels are normally non-aggressive, picking up an item like that will cause aggression, same as any other resource they catch you harvesting. Sentinel aggression is a setting for each individual planet. My most recent planet had poison sacs, with non-aggressive sentinels, but harvesting the sacs spawned sentinels to attack.